# How to delete all files in a directory and all sub-directories less than 100kb using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, recursion, foreach

I have directory with thousands of sub-directories for which I am trying to delete all files with sizes less than 100 kb.  I have the following script written; however, it deletes the sub-directory instead of deleting the individual files within it.

```
#root directory
$dir = "D:\S3\images"

#minimum size for file
$minSize = 100

#go through every item in the root directory
Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
#check if file length is less than 100kb 
  if ($_.Length / 100kb -lt $minSize) {
    Remove-Item $_ -Force
  } else {
    #file is too big to remove
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your length check is incorrect, you do not need to do a division. In addition, you may want to skip directories in your `Get-ChildItem` using the `-File` parameter.

Try:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Path $dir -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
#check if file length is less than 100kb 
  if ($_.Length -lt 100kb) {
    Remove-Item $_ -Force
  } else {
    #file is too big to remove
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, it worked the first time I ran it on a test directory, now I'm getting a ```Cannot find path``` error.  The path is clearly defined.

Answer (score 1):

I corrected the script with the following fixes:

```
#root directory
$path = "D:\S3\images"

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Include *.* -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
#check if file length is less than 100kb 
  if ($_.Length -lt 100kb) {
    Remove-Item $_ -Force
  } else {
    #file is too big to remove
  }
}
```